# Xcode doesn't show code when stops at breakpoints

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, debugging, breakpoints

I'm having this weird bug:
I put some breakpoints in my code, the debugger stops on them, but Xcode doesn't bring me to the file/line where breakpoints are. It just jumps to the project page where you edit your project settings (build phases, build settings, etc.). And when I go to the breakpoints navigator and click on a breakpoint, it doesn't take me to the breakpoint either.

I don't have a clue why this happen. Breakpoints in my other project work fine.

Have you ever had this problem? If someone could help I would be very greatful. It's really annoying.

I'm using Xcode 4.2.

Comment: Are the files still part of the project?

Comment: Huh.... Sorry, I've got nothing

Comment: OK :) Thank you anyway. If you think about something don't forget to share your thoughts.

Comment: @bob The Same problem happening here as well. Have you solved that issue. if so could you share that please..

Comment: @Vinoth Unfortunately I didn't solve that problem. But for some reason it has disappeared, I still don't understand why ...

Comment: No pblm thanks for your reply buddy.. same here its working perfectly now..

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, running Xcode 4.2 under Mac OS 10.6.8.
Here's what worked for me:

`Product Menu-->Debug Workflow-->Show Disassembly When Debugging`

Make sure this option is not checked.

Comment: == Xcode 11 ==

Check if there is a tick is on the following option, if there is a tick , uncheck it. From the Xcode Menus -> Debug -> Debug workflow -> Show Disassembly / Always show Disassembly.Thanks this option uncheck is saved the day. I have edited it to support with Xcode 11.

Answer (score 2):

Modifications to the @user3308886 & @El Capitan v2.0 answer to support for Xcode 11

**== Xcode 11 ==**

Check if there is a tick is on the following option, if there is a tick , **uncheck it**.

**From the Xcode Menu**

```
Debug -> Debug workflow -> Show Disassembly / Always show Disassembly.
```

Answer (score 1):

Same bug happen to me as well,

1) I just clean my project and compiled it again.

2) Restarted my Xcode and it worked for me.

Comment: I tried that too. But it didn't work for me. I even tried to remove files in .xcodeproj folder (except project.pbxproj of course). Even that didn't work.

Comment: Try == Xcode 11 ==

Check if there is a tick is on the following option, if there is a tick , uncheck it. From the Xcode Menus -> Debug -> Debug workflow -> Show Disassembly / Always show Disassembly.